# Why is implementation using `std::view` and PSTL slower?

Tags: c++, c++17, std-ranges

I just learned about PSTL recently and I am experimenting with it. I don't understand why the following codes behave so differently. Here are the codes:

---

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

const long n = 1000;
long dp[n][n];

int main() {
  // init
  for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dp[i][0] = dp[0][i] = 1;
  }
  // dp, dp[i][j] = max((dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000, k < j)
  for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (long j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      dp[i][j] = -1;
      for (long k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        dp[i][j] = std::max(dp[i][j], (dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("res = %ld\n", dp[n - 1][n - 1]);
}
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <execution>

const long n = 1000;
long dp[n][n];

int main() {
  // init
  for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dp[i][0] = dp[0][i] = 1;
  }
  // dp, dp[i][j] = max((dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000, k < j)
  for (long i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    for (long j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      auto view = std::views::iota(0, j)
        | std::views::transform([&i](long k) { 
            return (dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000;
          })
        | std::views::common;
      auto it = std::max_element(std::execution::par, view.begin(), view.end());
      dp[i][j] = *it;
    }
  }
  printf("res = %ld\n", dp[n - 1][n - 1]);
}
```

---

And then I compile and run both of them:

```
➜  ~ g++ -std=c++2a -Ofast -march=native a.cpp -o a
➜  ~ g++ -std=c++2a -Ofast -march=native b.cpp -o b
➜  ~ time ./a
res = 998
./a  0.79s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.804 total
➜  ~ time ./b
res = 998
./b  3.22s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.221 total
```

Even more surprisingly, `-O2` is faster than `-O3`:

```
➜  ~ g++ -Wall -std=c++2a -O2 -march=native b.cpp -o b -ltbb && time ./b
res = 998
./b  1.13s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.134 total
➜  ~ g++ -Wall -std=c++2a -O3 -march=native b.cpp -o b -ltbb && time ./b
res = 998
./b  3.18s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 3.180 total
```

Compiler version (I know it's old):

```
➜  ~ g++ --version                                 
g++ (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I definitely did not expect such drastic timing different but in the "opposite way", since `b.cpp` uses the parallel policy `std::execution::par`. I also looked at the assembly code, and it seems that `b.cpp` doesn't even call `std::max_element` anymore (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/aobThfhbM)), so I guess it means it's optimised out. Then how is it still slower?

Can someone provide insight on what I am doing wrong, and how I should "fix" it, in a way that still uses parallelised STL?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming I'm not misreading, you're compiling with `-O0` for the second one? Any performance measurements at that point are meaningless.

Comment: @ChrisMM You're not misreading :) I compile with both -Ofast and -O0. Also, it's using `std::execution::par`, so my intuition says that it should even be *more accurate* using -O0 (without any inlining, just pure arithmetic), but of course that might be wrong.

Comment: C++ and its stdlib relies heavily on inlining templates which in this case will most likely not occur and therefore ranges will end up as a gazillion of function calls. That’s hardly performant. Just use O2 or O3 (or Ofast).

Comment: @alagner Are you saying that in general, `std::ranges` and other STL functions will be slower than just plain loops? That sounds... bad? It's also annoying that I have to parallelise that `std::max_element` call myself

Comment: Please define "general". In my experience they are more-less comparable with raw loops on O3, but tend to be numerous times slower on O0 due to lack of inlining. I haven’t really tried parallel execution though.

Comment: @alagner Ignore that "in general". In the timings I showed in the post, `std::views` and `std::max_element(std::execution::par, ...)` is 4 times slower than a plain for loop. Should that be expected?

Comment: It’s not totally unexpected. For details you’d need to analyze if the range doesn’t create a copy or refer to sth by referencing a reference or some other multi-layer indirection. Plus, don’t expect parallelism to always be faster.

Comment: @alagner I guess I will spend some time in IDA later and look at the lower level output then. I have one more update: I found that `-O2` is 3x faster than `-O3`. This is in some sense expected, but I didn't think of it. I will add it to the post too.

Comment: Also final message I promise. The timing information indicates that the algorithm is NOT being parallelised - it says 99% cpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a satisfying answer that might help people in the future that find this question.

Firstly, I did not use `-ltbb`. It is required to enable parallelisation.

Also, the timing shows "99% cpu", which indicates that nothing is parallelised. Indeed, looking at the godbolt decompilation output, we see that all the functions are inlined, which matches my observation ("I also looked at the assembly code, and it seems that `b.cpp` doesn't even call `std::max_element` anymore"). However, it doesn't mean it's more optimised than `a.cpp`.

Finally, a better solution here is to instead parallelise the *j* loop. Note that for a fixed `i`, the `j` loop can be run in parallel without write data race (of course they can read from dp[i - 1][*] simultaneously).

Instead of comparing and writing with `dp[i][j]` directly in the `std::max` call, which will require reading and writing to it, I instead use a local variable that's probably stored as a register or something.

I also switched back to using `omp.h` after the discussion in the comments that STL might be slow. To be fair, it matches my usual observation too. Even `std::deque` is slower than a shitty one I write myself.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

// compile with -fopenmp

const long r = 50;
const long n = 5000;
long dp[r][n];

int main() {
  // init
  for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    dp[0][i] = 1;
  }
  // dp, dp[i][j] = max((dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000, k < j)
  for (long i = 1; i < r; i++) {
    dp[i][0] = 1;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (long j = 1; j < n; j++) {
      long max = -1;
      for (long k = 0; k < j; k++) {
        max = std::max(max, (dp[i - 1][k] + dp[i - 1][n - 1 - k]) % 1000);
      }
      dp[i][j] = max;
    }
  }
  printf("res = %ld\n", dp[r - 1][n - 1]);
}
```

Timing:

```
➜  ~ g++ -Wall -std=c++2a -O2 -march=native b.cpp -o b -fopenmp && time ./b
res = 998
./b  2.56s user 0.01s system 910% cpu 0.283 total
```

As you can see, 887% cpu is used. For `n = 20000` it only takes 3 seconds.

Comment: FWIW `#pragma omp` is not standard C++. I would suggest using tbb instead.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade I didn't know that, thanks for the information! I will try tbb as well. Doesn't STL use tbb as a parallel backend? Why can't it be fast then :(